# Arduino Ethernet server: How to avoid denial of service?

Tags: arduino, ethernet

The Arduino Ethernet (board or shield) supports a maximum of 4 connections. If acting as a server, it is very easy to cause a denial of service: just open 4 connections to the Arduino without sending any data. The server code will never realize that connections were established, as the EthernetServer::available() method only returns an EthernetClient when the connection has data available. The connections will thus remain open for as long as the client maintains them, preventing the Arduino from processing other requests, without an opportunity for the server to close them after some time.

So the question is: is there a way to set a timeout on idle connections, maybe at the Wiznet chip level?

Comment: If this is the case I'm not sure even a timeout on idle connections would help against most denial of service attacks because many are consistently brute forcing their target

Comment: True, but I'm more concerned about bugs or bad behaviors in clients than actual malicious attacks. In my case the Arduino isn't public facing.

Comment: IMHO this is one of the many reasons why an Arduino is just not suitable as a server. I would suggest to go for something with more horsepower, e.g. a RASPI or some open-wrt router.

Comment: The horsepower is more than enough in this case (most of the CPU time is spent idling). I just need a way to shut down inactive connections after some time.

Answer (score 0):

As background information, the GET HTTP model of a dialog is called "stateless" what this means is that the connection can be closed and then re-opened with no loss of information.

However, there is an HTTP keyword where the browser can ask to keep a connection open.

The server is allowed to close a connection, in fact HTTP/1.1 defines a message from the server to browser that does just that.

So, in an Arduino where you control all of the software (TCP/IP stack and server code), then you should be to modify the WizNEt libs or add your own wrappers that time-out a dialog and close it, independent of what the browser is doing.

Thus, no DNS (or at least the keep the line open style of DNS).

Get the HTTP/1.1 spec (it is on the web) for more information and specifics.

Comment: Thanks, but what I actually need is a mean to implement the timeout. Hopefully without modifying the original libraries. And this has nothing to do with HTTP by the way.